# Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I downloaded a project from github which was dated back of 2013 and tired to run on my android studio version 4.1.3 but it gives me following error

> Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip'.

i am a noob and don't know much about android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a more recent version of gradle.

Goto file `gradle-wrapper.properties` and set the `distributionUrl` as `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-all.zip`

Comment: thanks bro now it started gradle building

Comment: which other files i need to fix to latest version as it now says gradle  version 1.10 is required

Comment: Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 4.4.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Gradle Settings.